# How can I `usermod` old users with new `/etc/skel` files?

Tags: configuration, home, etc

I want to "update" old users with new `/etc/skel` content on Debian and Ubuntu installations. Scripting this is possible...

```
find /home -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read homedir; do
    user="$(stat -c%U $homedir)"
    su -c 'tar -cf- -C /etc/skel . | tar -vxf- -C $HOME' $user
done
```

...but I'm wondering if anyone knows a better way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are running. Also, why would you run `chown -R` on _everything_ in a directory only to change the ownership of the skel files? You could break all sorts of things for users there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: What do you want to happen with files that already exist? Do you want to overwrite your user's existing bashrc files with the new ones in `/etc/skel`? What about any modifications your users may have made?

Comment: @roaima yes, granted, but mine clobbers while yours does not.
I'd prefer _not_ to clobber, but for my purposes, this is damage I can live with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update the `/etc/skel` files in users' directories with a script like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
getent passwd |
    while IFS=: read -r username x uid gid gecos home shell
    do
        if [ ! -d "$home" ] || [ "$username" == 'root' ] ## || [ "$uid" -lt 1000 ]
        then
            continue
        fi
        tar -cf - -C /etc/skel . | sudo -Hu "$username" tar --skip-old-files -xf -
    done
```

Notes

- Intentionally, it will not update files that already exist, but it cannot identify files a user has deleted that you want to put back again so those will be recreated
- It will not update `root`'s files at all
- Remove the `##` from the `if ...conditions...` should you want to exclude system accounts with UID<1000 too

If you had the original files available, an alternative approach could be to update users' files if and only if they were unchanged, and otherwise to install them alongside (much like Debian's `*.dpkg-dist` approach). But that would need a different approach than using `tar`.

Comment: Not updating existing files is very reasonable (I'd be annoyed if my sysadmin deleted my bashrc!). However, since these are skel files, most of them will exist already by definition, making this a little pointless.

Comment: @terdon sorry, making what a little pointless? As asked, it will bring in new files from `/etc/skel`. My note was that for example, if you intentionally had deleted a system provided `.bash_profile` because you preferred `.profile` then the deleted file would be reinstated from `/etc/skel`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see the logic for deleted ones. But since the OP mentioned "updating" users, I assumed there were new things in the skel files that weren't there when the users were created and now need to be added. In that scenario, leaving the existing files untouched wouldn't help. On the other hand, blindly changing them would be even worse, so your approach is better. It just renders the whole thing moot if the objective is to update the existing files. Not that I have a better idea.

Comment: Please, for the love of God add something like `[[ ${uid} -lt 1000 ]] && continue` to the otherwise useful script. Otherwise, on Debian, users like _daemon_ (homedir `/usr/bin`), _sys_ (homedir `/dev`) and others would see changes in their respective homes as well.

Answer (score 1):

For people finding this question who are using FreeBSD, the command

```
pw usermod user -m
```

will do exactly this. Note that you can also use `-k dir` to choose a different skeleton directory as part of this command as well.

Comment: Nice. I'm filing this under reasons to prefer BSD over Linux.